# Storm UI- Error on Spout when submitting topology

Tags: apache-storm

I'm quite new to all of this. I am trying to run a topology from RIOT benchmark on storm UI but when I submit the topology I get this error [error msg in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQOcP.png) on spout. I am unable to understand it please help me with this.I already run the word count topology successfully on Storm Ui

I want to run this topology and analyze the data latency and throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Obiously, there was a problem while reading a file as the `NullPointerException` ocurred. Are sure that the file path is correct? However, without providing your code it is hard to tall what is actually wrong.